# Change Color of Element on Click and Mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, mouseover

I am trying to write a code that make it so that an element will come to the front using a higher z-index when clicked, which I seem to have figured out, and I am trying to make that element maintain a different color identifying it as the current page. I would like to allow a mouseover function though to change the color of the other elements to identify them as other buttons, and these elements look like file tabs so it looks mush better this way. Unfortunately, I added a javascript code so that the elements will go back to the original gradient color when another is clicked, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a mouseover function to work for each individual element. I don't know if this makes any sense to you.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    // Change this selector to find whatever your 'boxes' are
    var boxes = $("div.menuitem");

    // Set up click handlers for each box
    boxes.click(function() {
        var el = $(this), // The box that was clicked
            max = 0;

        // Find the highest z-index
        boxes.each(function() {
            // Find the current z-index value
            var z = parseInt( $( this ).css( "z-index" ), 10 );
            // Keep either the current max, or the current z-index, whichever is higher
            max = Math.max( max, z );
        });

        // Set the box that was clicked to the highest z-index plus one
        el.css("z-index", max + 1 );
    });
});
    $(document).ready(function()
        {


    $("#productmenu").mouseover(function() { $("#productdropdown").css('visibility','visible'); });
    $("#productdropdown").mouseover(function() { $("#productdropdown").css('visibility','visible'); });
    $("#productdropdown").mouseout(function() { $("#productdropdown").css('visibility','hidden'); });
    $("#productmenu").mouseout(function() { $("#productdropdown").css('visibility','hidden'); }); 

        });
    $(document).ready(function()
        {


    $("#productmenu").click(function() { $("#couponmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#productmenu").click(function() { $("#contestmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#productmenu").click(function() { $("#contactmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#couponmenu").click(function() { $("#productmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#couponmenu").click(function() { $("#contestmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#couponmenu").click(function() { $("#contactmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#contestmenu").click(function() { $("#couponmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#contestmenu").click(function() { $("#productmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#contestmenu").click(function() { $("#contactmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#contactmenu").click(function() { $("#productmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#contactmenu").click(function() { $("#contestmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });
    $("#contactmenu").click(function() { $("#couponmenu").css('background','linear-gradient(0deg, #F90, #D76B00)'); });

        })
        </script>
```

I included a CSS like this which each element, but the javascript prevents it from working:

```
#productmenu:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(0deg, #FF972F, #FFD3A8);
    z-index:500;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
<div id="productmenu" class="menuitem" onclick="this.style.background='linear-gradient(0deg, #FF972F, #FFD3A8)',style.zIndex='500';">Products</div>
<ul id="productdropdown">
<li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
</ul>
</a>
<a href="#">
<div id="contestmenu" class="menuitem" onclick="this.style.background='linear-gradient(0deg, #FF972F, #FFD3A8)',style.zIndex='500';">Contest</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
<div id="couponmenu" class="menuitem" onclick="this.style.background='linear-gradient(0deg, #FF972F, #FFD3A8)',style.zIndex='500';">Coupon</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
<div id="contactmenu" class="menuitem" onclick="this.style.background='linear-gradient(0deg, #FF972F, #FFD3A8)',style.zIndex='500';">Contact</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go man.  Took me awhile to figure out what it was you wanted.  Your HTML and CSS needs some work as it's definitely not up to best practices.

## [Here's a fiddle with it working](http://jsfiddle.net/qe5q9uL3/)

We dropped the `<a>` tags from wrapping your `div`s.  You shouldn't do that in the future, as `<a>` elements are inline while `div`s are blocks.

**HTML**

```
<div id="productmenu" class="menuitem"><a>Products</a>
    <ul id="productdropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

We also got rid of a lot of your JavaScript, as most of that can be done better with CSS, so we excised this whole section:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#productmenu").mouseover(function() { $("#productdropdown").css('visibility','visible'); });
  $("#productdropdown").mouseover(function() { $("#productdropdown").css('visibility','visible'); });
  $("#productdropdown").mouseout(function() { $("#productdropdown").css('visibility','hidden'); });
  $("#productmenu").mouseout(function() { $("#productdropdown").css('visibility','hidden'); }); 
});
```

That whole thing is gone, because mostly it doesn't make sense.

And here's the CSS that's going to take over most of the hard work:

**CSS**

```
[id$=menu]:hover > a,
[id$=menu] li:hover > a {
    background:linear-gradient(0deg, #FF972F, #FFD3A8);
}
[id$=menu]:hover ul {
    display: block;  
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
[id$=menu] ul {
    display: none;
}
[id$=menu] a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, okay, I did use an old file to create this so I had some framework in place. I have been correcting some issues along the way, but I created a JSFiddle just to make it a bit easier to visualize. This is what I am trying to deal with:

http://jsfiddle.net/xexof7by/